# XML Library Missing in Scala Eclipse Distribution

Tags: scala

I need to use Scala's XML processing capabilities, but the XML library has been removed from Scala 2.11.x. On Scala's website, it shows instructions on how to get the library using SBT. I don't use SBT -- I use their Eclipse editor (the Scala IDE). How / where do I get the XML libraries when using the Scala IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download required version from [Scala site](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.4.html). In extracted archive find

scala/scala-2.11.4/lib/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar

Just add this jar to your Eclipse project Build Path.